# Informatica_Reader_1_1 : ERROR OPENING FILE [/Users/triti/OneDrive/Desktop/used_bikes.csv] Operating system error message [No such file or directory]

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

i am learning informatica powercenter and have created a mapping with aggregator transformation averaging prices by city. Both the source and target exist in the same directory. I only have client installed so cannot access the default target files location. Can someone tell what could be the possible reasons? [Session Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMG7L.png)

I provided the source and output file path during configuring the mapping in workflow manager. But this error keeps re-occurring.I also tried changing the files (both source and target) to a new directory, still no change.

Comment: I assume you are running the on-premise Informatica rather than the Cloud version? If so, then the Informatica server needs to be able to access the file - does that directory path/file exist on the server where Informatica is running? If it's only on your local PC where you are running the Infa client then that won't work as the server won't be able to access it

Comment: I see. So I should either switch to cloud version or connect to a database which is accessible by the server. I'll also have to query on cloud since local server won't be able to access the target files existing on infra server. Am I correct?

Comment: If you switched to Cloud then you'd have to run an agent on your local PC as Infa Cloud can talk to the agent and the agent can access files on that PC. If you run Infa on a server then the files need to be accessible from that server e.g. via a mapped drive or whatever mechanism works for your environment

Answer (score 0):

Please note that with PowerCenter client you work on your machine. Your laptop, your VDI - whatever that is. You can import local file definitions and save those definitions in repository.

But when you try to execute the flow, it is being executed on a PowerCenter server. And the server does not have access to your local files. You need to put the file on a location accessible by the server and give proper details in the session properties.

Good luck!